# How to install muffler gasket on chainsaw?

Tags: small-engine

**How to install muffler gasket on chainsaw?**

Do I simply put the gasket on? Do I need to apply gasket sealant/sealer, oil, or grease?

I have a Husqvarna 450 Rancher chainsaw. The old gasket between the muffler and the heat deflector plate melted, so I need to replace the gasket.

Gasket item number is 544084401.

Old gasket:

[image: Old gasket]

Comment: Post a picture of the gasket, so we can understand what kind of gasket material it is made of

Comment: Very likely that you would apply it dry, with no "goop" but also kind of odd that a gasket in a high heat location would melt...

Comment: Gasket item number is 544084401. You can image search it for new gasket. I have attached an image of the old gasket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the gasket fried because it developed a leak and over time the hot exhaust gasses degraded the gasket even further.

You should ensure that both surfaces are flat and free of any bumps, ridges or indents that could further exacerbate the issue once you fix the issue with a new gasket.

There are [exhaust gasket sealers](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=exhaust%20gasket%20sealer) if you determine that you have an indent on either surface, possibly from exhaust gasses passing over the manifold or the head for an extended period of time.  I would only use the exhaust gasket sealer under those conditions.

If the surfaces are in good shape and completely level without anything interfering with a good seal, then place the gasket dry without any sealer.